# Clearing values in VBA code?

Tags: vba, solidworks

I have written a macro for Solidworks using VBA. The macro saves all open drawing files as a PDF (gathering information from the referenced model within the drawing file to build the file name) into a folder it creates in the directory of the opened drawing file then closes the drawing and moves on to the next one.

My problem is it saves all the PDFs from any of the open drawing files into the same folder that it creates from the first drawing. So if I have multiple projects I am working on all the PDFs go in to the first folder created, this is the case until I restart the computer.

Do I need to clear some values or references so it can do multiple projects with the same macro?

Please note there are some double ups and unnecessary stuff in here but its just because while Im working through it I want to keep some options open for the future before I forget about them!

```
Option Explicit
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swDraw As SldWorks.DrawingDoc
Dim swCustProp As CustomPropertyManager
Dim valOut1 As String
Dim valOut2 As String
Dim resolvedValOut1 As String
Dim resolvedValOut2 As String

Dim ConfigName As String
Dim PartNo As String
Dim FullName As String
Dim nFileName As String
Dim swView As SldWorks.View
Dim PDFpath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim currpath As String

Sub main()

    Dim swDocs As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

    swDocs = swApp.GetDocuments
    For i = 0 To UBound(swDocs)
        Set swModel = swDocs(i)
        If swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING Then

        currpath = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, "\"))
        Filename = Right(swModel.GetPathName, Len(swModel.GetPathName) - InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\"))
        PDFpath = currpath & "PDF"

            Set swDraw = swModel
            Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
            Set swView = swView.GetNextView
            Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument

            currpath = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, "\"))
            Filename = Right(swModel.GetPathName, Len(swModel.GetPathName) - InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\"))
            PDFpath = currpath & "PDF"

            If (swModel.GetType = swDocPART) Then
                Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument
                Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
                Set swView = swView.GetNextView
                ConfigName = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
                FullName = swModel.GetTitle
                PartNo = Left(FullName, Len(FullName) - 7)

                Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager(ConfigName)
                swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
                swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2

                If Dir(PDFpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir PDFpath

                    nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & ConfigName & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & resolvedValOut1

                    swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

                    'MsgBox nFileName & ".PDF" + " Saved as a PDF"

                    swApp.QuitDoc swDraw.GetPathName

                ElseIf (swModel.GetType = swDocASSEMBLY) Then

                    Set swView = swDraw.GetFirstView
                    Set swView = swView.GetNextView
                    Set swModel = swView.ReferencedDocument
                    ConfigName = swView.ReferencedConfiguration
                    FullName = swModel.GetTitle
                    PartNo = Left(FullName, Len(FullName) - 7)

                    Set swCustProp = swModel.Extension.CustomPropertyManager("")
                        swCustProp.Get2 "Description", valOut1, resolvedValOut1
                        swCustProp.Get2 "Revision", valOut2, resolvedValOut2

                    If Dir(PDFpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir PDFpath

                    nFileName = PDFpath & "\" & PartNo & "-" & resolvedValOut2 & " " & resolvedValOut1

                    swDraw.SaveAs3 nFileName & ".PDF", 0, 0

                    swApp.QuitDoc swDraw.GetPathName
                End If
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox ("All open drawings saved as PDF!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "That was too fast and too furious.")

End Sub
```

Comment: First of all: why are you setting the currpath/Filename/PDFpath variables twice? Next, I would put a breakpoint on Filename and check what currpath is set to, as - judigng from your question - you seem to always be setting PDFpath to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

You're variable setting is all out of order it appears.

It appears `PDFpath` is derived from `currpath` is derived from `Filename`, however you don't set `Filename` til after `currpath`.

Try this:

```
    Filename = Right(swModel.GetPathName, Len(swModel.GetPathName) - InStrRev(swModel.GetPathName, "\"))
    currpath = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, "\"))

    PDFpath = currpath & "PDF"
```

---

**A few other suggestions since you said you're just getting started with programming:**

Pick a naming and capitalization convention and stick to it.  You can start with the [Microsoft Visual Basic Naming Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b283bse.aspx) described in the MSDN :)

Try to make your variable names as descriptive and appropriate as possible.  E.g. You have `Filename` but it's really not the filename, it's the full path of the file.  A better name would be `FullPath` or `FilePath`.  `FileName` would indicate the file name without the directory.

You are making multiple calls to the same procedure which just creates unnecessary overhead for your program.  Make the call once, store the value in a variable, and reference that variable as many times as needed.

Declare your variables nearer to where they are used; it's easier to see where they are used and prevents having to scroll back up and down to see what their declaration was.

Use [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) to your advantage - if you want to reset the variable, declare inside the loop block, it will go out of scope and get recreated each time the loop iterates. No need to clear it each time.